# Annotate seaborn Factorplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to visualize 2 boolean informations stored as columns in one seaborn FactorPlot.

Here is my df :

[image]

I would like to visualize both of `actual_group` and `adviced_group` in the same FactorPlot.

For now I am only able to plot the `adviced_groups` using the `hue` parameter :

[image]

with the code below :

```
 _ = sns.factorplot(x='groups',
                    y='nb_opportunities',
                    hue='adviced_groups',
                    size=6,
                    kind='bar',
                    data=df)
```

I tried to use the `ax.annotate()` from matplotlib without any success, because - for what I understood - Axes are not handled by the `sns.FactorPlot()` method.

It could be an annotation, colorize one of the rectangle's edge or anything that could help visualize the actual group.

The result could be for instance something like this :

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a snippet of the `dataframe`?

Comment: @NickilMaveli just did !

Comment: You could use the `ax` attribute on the object that `factorplot` returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make use of [`plt.annotate`](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) method provided by `matplotlib` to make annotations for the `factorplot` as shown:

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'groups':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'nb_opportunities':[674, 140, 114, 99],
                   'actual_group':[False, False, True, False],
                   'adviced_group':[False, True, True, True]})
print (df)

  actual_group adviced_group groups  nb_opportunities
0        False         False      A               674
1        False          True      B               140
2         True          True      C               114
3        False          True      D                99
```

**Data Operations:**

Choosing the subset of `df` where the values of `actual_group` are True. The `index` value and the `nb_opportunities` value become the arguments for x and y that become the location of the annotation.

```
actual_group = df.loc[df['actual_group']==True]
x = actual_group.index.tolist()[0]
y = actual_group['nb_opportunities'].values[0]
```

**Plotting:**

```
sns.factorplot(x="groups", y="nb_opportunities", hue="adviced_group", kind='bar', data=df, 
               size=4, aspect=2)
```

Adding some padding to the location of the annotation as well as the location of text to account for the width of the bars being plotted.

```
plt.annotate('actual group', xy=(x+0.2,y), xytext=(x+0.3, 300),
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05, headwidth=20, width=7))
plt.show()
```

[image]